# How do I send a object into the Jquery $('calendar') selector from outside

Tags: ember.js

In the below code, in the didInsertElement, I want to send myController object in to the JQuery Selector ('#calendar').How can I do this. Is it possible to do this. This might be easy. Any one please

```
(function () {
  App.EventDisplayCalendarDisplayView = Ember.View.extend({

    didInsertElement: function () {
        //I got the controller object here, now I want to pass this in to the JQuery calendar selector below.
        // How to do this
        var myController = this.get('controller');

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            weekends: true,
            events: this.get('controller'),
            dayClick: function(start, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                //I want to access the controller here how to do this.
                var controller = myController;  //This does not work.



            },
            eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views

            views: {
                agenda: {
                    eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(xEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                debugger;
                alert("Title: " + xEvent.title             //Get the event title
                    + "\n StartTime: " + xEvent.start    //Get the event start date
                    + "\n EndTime: " + xEvent.end        //Get the event end date
                );
                console.log(xEvent); //See your console for all event properties/objects
            }

        });

    },
    willDestroyElement: function () {

    }
  });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into calling the function with `.bind(variable)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.got it.